# How does the edge function calculate the threshold automatically in the edge function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

In the image processing toolbox of MATLAB, the edge function calculates the threshold for detecting edges for any specified method automatically(unless we specify it manually). This function adjusts the threshold values by itself and it is different for different images. Can somebody explain what underlying algorithm does the edge function actually use to decide the most optimal threshold value as per the image?

Comment: I have no idea what MATLAB uses. A suitable threshold for edge detection should be a little above the noise level. If the image is not "fully covered with edges", the average gradient magnitude is a starting point. But no global threshold will work if the image is heterogeneous (smooth and textured areas).

Comment: the function doc has in the bottom references and explanations